# Why it is taking some time to call the next activity after pressing back button?

Tags: android

Can any one suggest me why specifically for a single activity where i have implement the Camera API to draw some graph, the back button of my device is working too late. It is not calling the next activity immediately when i am pressing back button.  This is what my back() looking like:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        mp.release();   
        Canvas.freeGlCaches();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        timer.cancel();
        heart_Anim.stop();
        //Calling Home Page
        Intent i=new Intent(Graph.this,Home.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: You haven't accepted a single answer! Accept answers first, ask questions later!

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question, but I'm putting it as "useful info".

Just a quick note that `Canvas.freeGlCaches()` is no longer in the API as of API 11:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes/android.graphics.Canvas.html

Some of my apps have started to crash due to this method being called.